# Using CURL and PHPSimpleHTMLDOMParser gives me - 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, here you can check more about it: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

And also i am using a CURL because this web adress http://www.sportsdirect.com is not loading on the normal examples from the SimpleHTMLDom.

So here is the code i use:

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$curl = curl_init(); 

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/'); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
 $str = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl);  
  
 $html= str_get_html($str); 

echo $html->plaintext;
?>
```

When i try to load the script it gives me: **500 Internal Server Error**

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@superweb.bg and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This script is just not working for this web adress, because when i try to load other website like mandmdirectDOTcom it is woking OKEY!

Where is my mistake and how i can make this thing works?

Comment: Check your server logs. Instead of this class you can also use symfony dom crawler, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the `curl` fetch. It works for me in this case. This is a standard set of curl options & settings I use that work well:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = str_get_html($str); 

echo $html->plaintext;
```

I believe the issue with your original `curl` settings was the missing user agent. Try the same script with the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` line commented out to see what I mean.

Many servers have firewall settings that disallow `curl` requests from users making requests without a proper user agent setting. The user agent I have set here is a fairly generic Firefox user agent, so feel free to experiment with that to use something else.

Comment: Thank you so much man! Your solution works just PERFECTLY! God bless you, you and your family!!!

Comment: @user3788452 FYI you were only missing the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a Host header in the request. It's possible that the target domain is on a shared server, and without a Host header, the server doesn't know what to do.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.sportsdirect.com'));
```

Comment: This! perfect! a relief after 6h debugging! great!